# How to pass variables to a class in c#

Tags: c#, class, variables

I've this simple code:

```
class ResourceInterceptor: IResourceInterceptor
        {

            public bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
            {
                return false;
            }

            ResourceResponse IResourceInterceptor.OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
            {
                request.Referrer = "http://www.google.com";
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I would need to pass a variable to the class (just read it, do not edit), but if I insert a variable not declared within the class it gives me this error:

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' via nested type
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.ResourceInterceptor'

For example i need somethin like this (obviously doesn't works!)

```
public string referrer = "www.google.com";
class ResourceInterceptor: IResourceInterceptor
        {

            public bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
            {
                return false;
            }

            ResourceResponse IResourceInterceptor.OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
            {
                request.Referrer = referrer;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you need to pass where? Please show what you are actually trying.

Comment: please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), that is a short *compilable* example. This is just a random piece of code.

Comment: Can you make the referrer  as `public static string referrer` ?

Comment: @SenJacob public editable fields shouldn't exist.. maybe through a property though.

Comment: @Default Could you explain the reason for that? Is there any problem with public fields? Is it for the sake of encapsulation or is there any other reason?

Comment: Let me guess, I've to read this discussion. [Properties vs. Public Variables](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html)

Comment: @SenJacob nice article. No problem per se with public fields, encapsulation, exactly. However, IMO a `string Refererrer{ get; set; }` is just as simple as a public field, and more easily refactored into a backing store later, because you don't have to change the calling code. If the field is a complex type the property can as well give out the common interface used, thus easing refactoring even more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28423/discussion-between-sen-jacob-and-default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an initializing constructor. For example:

```
class ResourceInterceptor: IResourceInterceptor
{
    public ResourceInterceptor(string referer)
    {
        m_Referer = referer;
    }

    public bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ResourceResponse IResourceInterceptor.OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        request.Referrer = m_Referrer;
        return null;
    }

    private string m_Referer;
}
```

And then simply pass the referer to the constructor when you create an instance of the class:

```
ResourceInterceptor interceptor = new ResourceInterceptor("www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, if you only need that variable in all class instances is to use a class (`static`) property:

```
class ResourceInterceptor : IResourceInterceptor
{
    // Public class property.
    public static string Referer { get; set; }
    ResourceResponse IResourceInterceptor.OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        request.Referrer = Referer;
        return null;
    }
}

// Somewhere else...
ResourceInterceptor.Referer = "www.google.com";
```

After this, all your `ResourceInterceptor` instances will share the same `Referer` class attribute.

Comment: In this case it's even easier to use a static field instead of static property.